# Python web scraping using Selenium: clicking on next page

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

I am looking to find a way to do some web scraping with Python 3 and using Selenium. On some of the pages of interest, there are some arrows that point to the next page. [Here](https://www.nae.edu/default.aspx?id=20412&groupby=Election%20Year&sortdir=descending) is an example website.

As can be seen, there are some left and right arrows pointing to the previous/next pages. Here is a screenshot of what I am talking about:

[image]

I tried to use the `Inspect` on Chrome browser, but could not find the element associated with the arrows so I can navigate different pages.

I would like to know what element is associated with this action.

Also, it there any simpler way of scraping all the pages other than using Selenium?

Comment: all the `li` under `//ul[@class="pagination"]`

Comment: Can you please provide the code that does click? driver.find_element_by_xpath("ul[@class='pagination']").click() would work? How do I select left arrow or right arrow?

Comment: Button has unique `next_page` css class, use `driver.find_element_by_class_name("next_page")`

Comment: You try to use requests package to scrape data

Comment: Right-click and Inspect on the arrow will show you the element that you need to click to move to the next page. What's the issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the class names in css selector

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.pager-pagenextb').click()
```

HTML:

[image]

You may also want a expected conditions wait clickable

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".pager-pagenextb"))).click()
```

---

**additional imports for wait**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the x path of the right (next) arrow.
[image: Right next arrow]

```
//[@id="ctl07_ctl07_ctl00_MembersList_members_ctl01_ctl20_filterTopPager_lbNext"]
```

you can now use

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl07_ctl07_ctl00_MembersList_members_ctl01_ctl20_filterTopPager_lbNext"]').click()
```

If it does not work you can try implementing a driverWait

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".pager-pagenextb")))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `class` attribute to click on the element to get next page.Let me know if this work.

```
element=WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH ,"//a[@class='next_page']")))
element.click()
```

If WebDriver click do not work then try JS executor to click on the element.

```
element=WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH ,"//a[@class='next_page']")))      
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

You need to import followings.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Answer (score 0):

To click to next page button you can use css class:

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("next_page")
```

For scraping use `BeautifulSoup` and `requests`:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'DNT': '1',
}

params = (
    ('id', '20412'),
    ('groupby', 'Election Year'),
    ('sortdir', 'descending'),
)

response = requests.post('https://www.nae.edu/default.aspx', headers=headers, params=params)
page = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

__VIEWSTATE = page.find(attrs={"id": "__VIEWSTATE"}).attrs["value"]
__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR = page.find(attrs={"id": "__VIEWSTATE"}).attrs["value"]
__EVENTVALIDATION = page.find(attrs={"id": "__EVENTVALIDATION"}).attrs["value"]
last_page = int(page.select_one(".pager-pageddl option:last-child").text)

for i in range(0, last_page - 1):
    if i > 0:
        __VIEWSTATE = page.find(attrs={"id": "__VIEWSTATE"}).attrs["value"]
        __VIEWSTATEGENERATOR = page.find(attrs={"id": "__VIEWSTATE"}).attrs["value"]
        __EVENTVALIDATION = page.find(attrs={"id": "__EVENTVALIDATION"}).attrs["value"]

        data = {
            '__EVENTTARGET': 'ctl07$ctl07$ctl00$MembersList$members$ctl01$ctl21$filterTopPager$lbNext',
            '__VIEWSTATE': __VIEWSTATE,
            '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR': __VIEWSTATEGENERATOR,
            '__EVENTVALIDATION': __EVENTVALIDATION,
            'ctl07$ctl07$ctl00$MembersList$members$ctl01$ctl20$filterTopPager$ddlPageIndex': str(i),
            'ctl07$ctl07$ctl00$MembersList$members$ctl01$ctl20$filterTopPager$ddlPageSize': '20',
            'ctl07$ctl07$ctl00$MembersList$members$ctl01$ctl21$filterBottomPager$ddlPageIndex': str(i),
            'ctl07$ctl07$ctl00$MembersList$members$ctl01$ctl21$filterBottomPager$ddlPageSize': '20'
        }

        response = requests.post('https://www.nae.edu/default.aspx', headers=headers, params=params, data=data)
        page = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

    names = page.select(".flexible-list-item .initialState .name")
    for name in names:
        print(name.text)
```

Comment: the question uses selenium not beautiful soup